# NServiceBus set maxretries configuration in c#

Tags: c#, configuration, nservicebus

I'm currently using NServiceBus V5 and I would like to set the MaxRetries settings in the C# instead of the app.config of my endpoint.

I have the following code

```
public abstract class AEndpointConfiguration : IConfigureThisEndpoint
{
    public void Customize(BusConfiguration configuration)
    {
        ConfigureLogging();

        configuration.DisableFeature<SecondLevelRetries>();
        configuration.Transactions().Enable();
        configuration.UseSerialization<XmlSerializer>();
        configuration.EnableFeature<NServiceBus.Features.Sagas>();
        configuration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence>();
        configuration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(b => b.ExistingLifetimeScope(ConfigureBuilder()));
        configuration.UsePersistence<MsmqPersistence>().For(NServiceBus.Persistence.Storage.Subscriptions);
        configuration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();
        configuration.PurgeOnStartup(false);
    }
```

I have read the following article but it seems only work for V4

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/how-to-reduce-throughput-of-an-endpoint

Still looking how to do it...